# scipy stats distributions documentation

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to track down the docs for the various distributions in `scipy.stats`.  It is easy enough to google around for them, but I like to use the built-in `help` function for kicks sometimes.  Through a series of `help` calls, can find that `scipy` has a `stats` module and that `scipy.stats` has a `binom` distribution.  However, at that point, using `help` becomes tricky.  `help(scipy.stats.binom)` actually returns a help document for a `class` named `binom_gen` which inherits methods from some parent abstract class whose `__init__` method is utterly uninformative.  However, it does provide the following hint:  "See help(type(self)) for accurate signature."  Okay.  Since I do not have access to `self` from outside of the class code itself, I assume that this means "go ahead and instantiate an object, and then call `help`."  After some trial and error on getting literally any old parameters to not `raise` an `Exception` (specifically, `scipy.stats.binom(0.5,0.5)` returns successfully), we can call `help` on that thing.

Both `help(scipy.stats.binom(0.5,0.5))` and `help(type(scipy.stats.binom(0.5,0.5))` give the docs for `class rv_frozen`, which is equally uninformative, and actually gives the same suggestion to: "See help(type(self)) for accurate signature."

How do I access the `help` for distributions in `scipy.stats`?  More generally, is there a meaningful way to navigate an abstract class morass via successive calls to the `help` function, or must I simply know a priori the class ultimately returned by these factories?

Comment: Are you only interested in finding it from inside an IDE? Because [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) is the documentation for all of the distributions and functions in `scipy.stats`

Answer (score 1):

If you use ipython then I believe `scipy.stats.binom?` achieves this.

Comment: This is interesting, but I am specifically interesting in the `help` function.